# Check .NET Framework with a published C# WPF app

Tags: wpf, frameworks, version

I have this problem (about checking if the right version of the .NET Framework is installed)

I made a C# WPF app and it works very good in my development environment (XP with .NET Framework 4.0, MS Access).

When I deploy the app (with setup.msi and setup.exe files) the app works, too. It should verify by itself the .NET Framework because I checked the .NET prerequisite (download from the same location where the app is).

But, when the app is just published, I go to "Application Files" folder and doubleclick on the appName.exe and the app starts and I get this error: "To run this app you need .NET Framework 4.0 installed".

So the question is, how to check the .NET Framework (and eventually install it automatically) from/for the pubblished app ?

Thanks,
Adrian T.

Answer (score 0):

you can check Installed framework from control panel.

also as i think you have add .Net Client Framework instead of .Net Framework. sometime .Net Client framework is not working proper so add as prerequisite .Net framework instead of .Net client framework.

Comment: Thank you for you very quick answer :-)

Comment: Thank you for you very quick answer :-) I need to check when the published setup starts, I mean check something and then display "The .NET Framework 4.0 is not installed. Do you want to install it now ?". So if the user answers "YES" then the installing process (for .NET) starts and then it finishes and then the user can start the app.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to consider ClickOnce which will let you install the app and its prerequisites via a simple URL. If your app is signed with a digital certificate, you can also manage automatic updates that way.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I already tried ClickOnce. For now I don't want to use it. I manage the updates manually. The most important is how to check if the .NET Framework is installed from the setup.exe of the published app.